# Sails.js with mongodb design

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, model-view-controller, sails.js

just starting out in sails.

Currently I have a User Model set up.  I also have another Founder Model to store information specific to Users who are also Models.

```
attributes: {
    companyName: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    tagLine: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    location: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    market: {
        type: 'string',
      required: true
    }, 

    psName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    psDesc: {
      type: 'string'.
      required: true
    }
}
```

So my question in the FounderController...would inputting the unique id for the user from User for the database be implemented in the models or in the controller?  The Founder model will essentially create it's own unique id.

My first approach would to basically find the ID from the User documents, store it into a variable, update the Founder document's id field with the user id?

I felt this isn't very efficient.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure i'm following this perfectly, but it sounds like you are trying to just create a reference between the two models and their data.  You can do this  user: {model: 'user'}, then when you create the item you pass in the user it should be attached to. You can also check out the populate function when querying to get the referenced object. If i'm way off for what your looking for let me know.